# How to customize Spring Security switch user?

Tags: spring-security

I have enabled switch user in my web app. Now I'd like to do something similar on the mobile app however the target URL should be different.

On web app the target URL is `/account` (returns jsp)
On mobile app I expect the target URL to be `rest/member/account` (returns json)

I tried the following but it didn't do it

```
public class MySwitchUserFilter extends SwitchUserFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        if (request.getParameter("android") != null)
            this.setTargetUrl("/rest/member/account");
        else
            this.setTargetUrl("/account");
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

My Spring Security context

```
<beans:bean id="switchUserFilter"
        class="com.myapp.auth.MySwitchUserFilter">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
        <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
        <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/account" />
    </beans:bean>
```

When I execute below URL in browser I get `Access is Denied`

```
https://localhost:8443/business/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1
```

**Log**

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/authentication'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/forgot'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@fd6ed5da: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BrowserAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/authentication'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/forgot'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('ADMIN')]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1410588, returned: 1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MySwitchUserFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/rest/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/authentication'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/forgot'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@91b8a7a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@91b8a7a: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@194a73d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: MEMBER, Switch User Authority [ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR,org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN]'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BrowserAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@91b8a7a: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@194a73d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: MEMBER, Switch User Authority [ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR,org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN]'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1 at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/login'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/authentication'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/forgot'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/resources/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user'; against '/admin/**'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /admin/j_spring_security_switch_user?j_username=test&android=1; Attributes: [hasAnyRole('ADMIN')]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@91b8a7a: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@194a73d; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: MEMBER, Switch User Authority [ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMINISTRATOR,org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fd6ed5da: Principal: com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetails@1259255; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: EAE58863B5C733E17CDC0DFEEEE131CB; Granted Authorities: ADMIN]
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@1410588, returned: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doF
```

**Security Context**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- authentication manager and password hashing -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" name="userAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationUserDetailsGetter" />

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- declare the filter bean -->
    <beans:bean id="switchUserFilter"
        class="com.myapp.auth.MySwitchUserFilter">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/admin/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
        <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
        <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/account" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- web services-->
    <http use-expressions="true" pattern="/rest/**"
            disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" > 
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"
                requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/member/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN,MEMBER')"
                requires-channel="https" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/rest/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>

    <!-- browser -->
    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <custom-filter ref="switchUserFilter" position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="jqueryCaptchaProcessingFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/authentication" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/forgot" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/site_**" access="permitAll"
            requires-channel="https" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('MEMBER','ADMIN')"
            requires-channel="https" />
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/login"
            session-authentication-error-url="/login">
        </session-management>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="jqueryCaptchaProcessingFilter"
        class="com.myapp.auth.BrowserAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/authentication" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:bean class="com.myapp.auth.AuthenticationSuccessHandler">
                <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl"
                    value="true" />
                <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/account" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: So it is not working means are you getting an error or something? The code looks fine actually. I think this line looks shady, request.getParameter("android") != null .

Comment: I can only differentiate web request and android request from this parameter. Is there a better way ?

Comment: I am writing an answer, if it doesn't help you, let me know, I will delete it.

Comment: As I can see from the logs, your filter is getting fired, the problem is MySwitchUserFilter class. I would require more information, can you paste your spring security context?

Comment: Can you write an intercept url for your /rest/ methods and temporarily set permitAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the proper device in this way :

Set this on Android client :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "android");
```

[This will give you the headers.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

And check in the request header rather then parameters to see which device it is. 
Plus, telling that access was denied is hardly useful, turn on Spring-Security logger to debug and paste the stacktrace in your post.

Comment: This is the problem : DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler